# Next.js - nested dynamic api folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I working with next for creating a basic API tha read a local file json.

I would like to make a dynamic api base on what call recive

My api folder is

```
api
--book
---[id].js
----content
-----[id].js
```

So I could make a get request to https.../book/1
and also to https.../book/1/content/4

I'am right? Is possible do it?

I've try but with no good result

Thanks

Comment: if your logic is right, it would be `-book; --[id]; ---content; ----[id]` without the `.js`

Comment: No, because [id].js is where there is the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think you could do it like this:

```
api
  book // folder
    [bookId] // folder
      index.js // /api/book/1 endpoint
      content // folder
        [contentId].js // /api/book/1/content/4 endpoint
```

Edit: add image of folder structure

[image]

Comment: No, this is not right

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question. Are you trying to have /api/book/[someBookId] and /api/book/[someBookId]/content/[someContentId] as two valid endpoints? If so the above achieves this.

Comment: I have added an image of the folder structure i used and have tested both endpoints successfully.